# Should I show a progressbar or a drawable for each item of a listview?

Tags: android, drawable, android-progressbar, android-gui

There is a listview in my app, where I show a drawable for each item; since I retrieve those drawables from the internet it takes some times to load them, so I'm supposed to show the user a little indeterminate progress cycle for each drawable, until I got the picture.
My question is: what should I show in the meantime? I mean, should I show an animation into the drawable (is it even possible?) or a progressbar overlapped to the drawable? There are fields of tutorial which explain how to create and customize a progressbar, but I wasn't able to find a guideline about what's best to do in these cases...
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: google + Lazy image loader android ... it showing stub image first and then real image after loading is completed (or leave stub if loading fail) ...